# Quantum vs Classical Vorticities

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bose-einstein-condensate, vortex, superfluidity

Excepting the circulation quantization, what are the differences between classical vorticities (created in classical fluids) and quantum vorticities (BEC superfluids)?